# For some reason I am getting KeyError: 16 when range goes beyond '16'

Tags: python

The code runs fine till the value of `range(16)`.

```py
my_list = []

for i in range(17):
    if lead_data['m2all_enquiry_source'][i] == 'WEB':
        my_list.append(lead_data['number_of_attempts'][i])
    i = i + 1

my_list
```

Once I increase it to 17 I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 16
```

Comment: What is len(lead_data['number_of_attempts']) ?

Comment: It seems that `lead_data['m2all_enquiry_source']` has 16 objects (key: 0~15).